# How to get the index of an element of an array which contains a specific string

Tags: ruby, arrays

Suppose I have an array

```
["70 percent chance of rain", " 35 percent chance of snow"]
```

How would I get the index of the element which contains `"rain"`?

Comment: I know it's not what you asked, but you could make it into a hash: `weather = { :rain => 70, :snow => 70 }` And then just get the element like this: `weather[:snow]`

Comment: Maybe it is, but I was trying to help. No need to be rude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to use [`index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-index) method

```
array = ["70 percent chance of rain", " 35 percent chance of snow"]
index = array.index { |x| x.include?('rain') }  # gives 0
index = array.index { |x| x.include?('snow') } # gives 1
```

Note:- This will give you the index of the first occurrence of a string and if string is not present it will return `nil`

for ex:-  `percent` is present in both the array element so it will return `0`

```
index = array.index { |x| x.include?('percent') } # gives 0
```

'not present' is not present in any of the element so it will return `nil`

```
index = array.index { |x| x.include?('not present') } # gives nil
```

Comment: You could also use regex, `array.index { |i| i =~ /rain/ }`. Not sure which one would be faster.

Comment: @depa:- i agree you should use regex which works for you because it's fater than the `include?`